# Spring cloud steam registry and Avro schema files

Tags: rabbitmq, avro, spring-cloud-stream

I've setup the Spring Avro schema registry provided in Spring Cloud Stream for use in RabbitMQ. Most examples I see use the Maven Avro plugin to generate Java classes from schema resource files. The schema files are then registered in the schema registry. My understanding is that this registry enables a message to be serdes with just a reference to a registered schema instead of including the entire schema in the message. What I don't understand is how these schema files are subsequently distributed amongst all services at design-time to generate Java class files. The Maven plugin requires the schema files to be on the classpath. What is best practice in dealing with Avro schema definitions? Any advance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The message producer, defines the message format with the schema. Once done they register the schema in Schema registry and let the other services know what is the schema/schema id.

Then consumers can fetch the schema from schema registry and generate POJO classes based on the schema.

As time goes, producer may alter the schema (according to Avro rules), but still the consumer should be able to receive the messages without any change to the producer.